# JQuery Random word selector isnt working on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script on jsfiddle that works just fine: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tktmn36z/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myTagList = [
        'experianced',
        'self taught',
        'well rounded',
        'work oriented',
        'punctual',
        'imaginative',
        'awesome'
        ], i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#randomSelector').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#randomSelector').html(myTagList[i=(i+1)%myTagList.length]).fadeIn();
        });
    }, 2500);        
});
```

Although it doesnt seem to work on my site, it fades out the word then doesnt do anything else, heres the site: http://shixma.github.io/

Comment: Did you at least open the console and note that jQuery is missing / not loaded correctly ?

Comment: I just fixed that, it didnt do anything.

Comment: Working fine for me on the live site.

Comment: it just does this for me: http://gyazo.com/e82b9d26c5a862d7bfbfcdf55ec54f8c which it isnt supposed to do.

Comment: I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null` in `particles.min.js`, try removing that script and see if it works. Seems fine in Firefox but not in Chrome: 
 
http://gyazo.com/dc06c89688e52274b6cb8da538dd9f43

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup is the following:

```
<h1><span id="welcomeSelector" style="">Gamer</span></h1>
```

By inspecting the element above in chrome dev tools i could see the words change as you'd expect to, but the text wouldn't show up.
I tried setting a css z-index: 1 to the h1 elements and the text was again visible.

Comment: I added this to my stylesheet but it hasnt done anything: `#welcomeSelector {z-index: 1;}`

Comment: @Shixma I added the css rule to the h1 element.